# php mysql not validating if a record exists

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following in a php form, while no matter if I enter an email address already in the database, or a new email address, the response seems not as what I want. Any help is appreciate.

```
$eMailAddress = $_POST['eMailAddress'];

$sql = sprintf("SELECT eMailAddress FROM Membership WHERE eMailAddress='$eMailAddress' LIMIT 1");

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if ($result) {
    echo "Sorry your email is already in the system";
} else {
    // proceed with inserting record into database
}

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

Comment: why don't you set your email column as unique?

Comment: This is a fixed to an existing form. We already got some entries with people filling in their same email address a few times. So we couldn't change the eMailAddress as unique at this point.

Comment: Your mixing mysqli_* and mysql_* functions that is not possible

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind try this code and let me know. I've coded this using `mysqli_` prepared statements which makes it SQL injection proof. You should look in to using prepared statements as well.

**Using `mysqli` prepared statements**

```
$sql = $conn -> prepare("SELECT eMailAddress FROM Membership WHERE eMailAddress=?");
$sql -> bind_param("s", $_POST['eMailAddress']);
$sql -> execute();
$rowCounts = $sql -> num_rows();

if ($rowCounts > 0){
        echo "Sorry your email is already in the system";
    }else{
        // proceed with inserting record into database
    }

$row = $sql -> fetch_assoc();
```

**Using `PDO` prepared statements**

```
$sql = $conn -> prepared("SELECT eMailAddress FROM Membership WHERE eMailAddress=:email");
$sql -> bindParam(':email', $_POST['eMailAddress'], PDO:: PARAM_STR);
$sql -> execute();
$rowCounts = $sql -> rowCount();

if ($rowCounts > 0){
    echo "Sorry your email is already in the system";
}else{
    // proceed with inserting record into database
}

$row = $sql -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Tried it but it still giving me the result where it says "proceed with inserting record into database". Giving more information about the php form. It's based on WordPress as a template. Wonder if WordPress would stop some of the php functions where it comes to sql statement?

Comment: That means the `SQL` part of the code is not querying the table.

Comment: Don't just copy and paste the code, understand what the code is doing.

Comment: Now I tried the PDO version and it's not giving anything - but blank - neither of the result shows on the screen.

Comment: Yeah it should have done that there was a typo where the `bindParam` is so the variable was not bound to the place holder. The email your using is it already in the data base ? or not ?

Comment: "Tried it but it still giving me the result where it says "proceed with inserting record into database"

If you are seeing that it means the code is working. It is now up to you to create a INSERT query to store the values to the database.

Comment: I tried to enter an email which is already in the database. Then I tried an email which is not in the database. Both results giving me the same thing on the screen.

Comment: As I said it seems like the `SQL` is not querying the table. Is the DB connection getting made and can you run the same query in your data base and see what results it throws.

Comment: I tested the SQL statement and it gave me correct result, with an email address already in the database, and an email address not in the database. Funny thing is, when I tried it on the php file, it returns the $rowCounts as "0" for both cases.

Comment: Your variable `$_POST['eMailAddress']` it's not empty right ?

Comment: No it is not empty. I echo it and it did give me the value I passed through the form.

Comment: Well I stoned really if the data is passing and the SQL is ok then the last option is to check the connection. If that's also ok then I'm out of answers m8.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote it as follow and it's working now.

```
$sql="SELECT eMailAddress FROM Membership WHERE eMailAddress='$eMailAddress'";



if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
{
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if ($rowcount > 0) {

    echo "Your email address is already in our database. Please try again.";

  } else {

  // proceed with inserting new row

  }

}
  mysqli_free_result($result);
```